# How to convert varchar from sql server to Image in android

Tags: android, sql-server, blob, android-imageview, varchar

We have image stored in SQL Server as `blob` or `varchar` which is something similar to:

```
0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000...(Goes till 1945 characters).
```

How do I convert this to an `image` for imageview? Do i need to convert it into byte array or `Base64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a sequence of hexadecimal values. To convert to a byte array, strip off the "0x" at beginning, subdivide string in double character strings ("FF", "D8", "FF") and convert each to a byte by using `(byte) Integer.parseInt(s, 16)`.

Which image data format was used to store the image initially you must find out for yourself then.

Answer (score 0):

When I stored a BLOB in sqlite I saved it as a byte[]. Most people would suggest that you should save a reference to a path to where the picture is saved (I think this is mostly for local files). Maybe you can still use this approach and store a string representation of an URL to where the pic is stored in your server and then download it asynchronously.

Comment: yes i do agree saving reference to the path is best way.But  picture is already stored in database.